# Is there a way that VSO vNext builds can clean up long directory paths (>260 characters)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I've setup a .Net [TFS Build vNext](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2015/01/15/tfs-build-vnext-ndash-a-preview.aspx) build to run the following:

- npm install
- gulp
- visual studio solution build

The build is confgured to clean automatically before checking for sources like so:

[image: Clean Sources Configuration]

I have two problems with this build but this question is about problem #2.

1. The npm install step fails to install phantomjs because the command *node install.js* can't find *node*, even though node is in the System path.
2. Running builds configured to Clean fails because of the path too long error below.

### [error]The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I would like for the *Clean* setting to just work and clean up these longs paths, but I don't know how to make it work properly.

When I tried to re-create this same build in TeamCity the *Clean* option works just fine. Also, I know that if I had access to the script that is running the clean that it could just use a *rmdir /S /Q  to remove these paths. Hopefully the VSO build can just run this or something that works.

Comment: You could set Clean to `false` and take advantage of the pre-build script options to do a manual clean.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I didn't know it had any pre-build hooks. Is there any documentation available on that?

Comment: It is noted [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2015/03/05/adding-gulp-to-visual-studio-online-builds.aspx) under Step 3. It should be under the Build  or Options tab.

Comment: I believe that article is describing the XAML based VSO builds. I'm using the vNext builds which are only configurable from VSO itself and they don't provide a pre/post build option.

Comment: Ah, so you should add a build step before your solution build that runs your manual clean command.

Comment: I would typically just do that, but in this case I have another error that I didn't mention in the original question. After I re-run this build it immediately fails with the error: 

Syncing repository: Admin (Git)
Could not find a part of the path 'float.patch'.

After that I'm stuck and I can't run anymore builds. This seems to be a very complex question and perhaps should be broken down a bit more. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Are you getting that error because of your custom clean? You may have deleted something you shouldn't have.

Comment: Good question, but no I didn't have the custom clean step in place before I started getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] - I have confirmed that this is fixed in the latest Build agent version (1.85.1)

I've been told by MS folks that this is currently a bug in the vNext builds and will be fixed in the next release of the product. I'll update this answer once I see this fix released.

Comment: How are you updating your agents (and tasks if you are) Dan?

Comment: I'm actually getting the character limit errors when simply trying to run a gulp task.

Comment: There does still exist limitation with the max path issue. This specific fix was for the Repository "clean" setting only. 

For example I can't use the nuget restore task unless I do that before my npm install task because after running "npm install I will have directories > 260 character limit. Re-ordering has fixed the issue for me in that case. If you have more specifics please post another question and I'll see if I can assist.

Comment: I got passed my issue by upgrading to the pre-release NPM v3 releases. Apparently flattening of folders is baked in to npm install past V3.

Comment: Excellent. I'll give [npm v3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.2.1) a shot. Thanks.

Comment: How do you upgrade the VSO build agents to npm v3?

Answer (score 1):

From an admin console, run: `npm install npm -g`

Run `npm version` or `npm -v` to make sure it worked. Also note if you have node installed, you want to browse to the node directory and update it from there.

Also note vso agents sometimes store a local version. Browse to `agent/tasks/npm`.